# Web scraping question - not seeing data in page source

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get the product-related info on a category page. When I use inspect element, I can see all the info needed is in an attribute called data.

However I cannot see the value in page source or find the class name by selenium selector. It looks like this.

```
data="{{ activeColour.analyticsData }}
```

How can I get this attribute value? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This data may be appended to the source with XMLHttpRequest so that's why you can't find it on page source, For that you should take a look at "Developer Tools > Network".

Comment: full xpath did not work. but found json file in network. thanks!